# compact image of tuple of functions

Tags: general-topology

Assume that $f,g : X \rightarrow Y$ are two continuous functions between topological spaces such that the images $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are compact.

Is it necessarily true that the set $$\{(f(x),g(x)): \, x \in X\} \subseteq Y \times Y$$ is compact?

Of course it is when $X$ is compact, but if we don't know that then I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take $(f,g):X=[0,\infty) \to Y=\Bbb R$ defined by
$$
(f,g)(x)=
\begin{cases}
(x,\, 0) &\text{ if } x\le 1\\
(1/x,\, \sin(2\pi x)) &\text{ if } x\ge 1
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f(X)\times g(X) = I\times I$, but $(f,g)(X)$ is not closed.

Comment: What exactly are the individual functions f, g?

Comment: @user254665: I forgot to put the conditions for the argument into the function :-)

Comment: Good counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

Another example: with $X=[0,\infty)$ take $f(x)=e^{-x}\cos x,\ g(x)=e^{-x} \sin x.$ Each image of $f,g$ individually is a closed interval (so compact) yet the set of pairs $(f(x),g(x))$ give a spiral in the plane which approaches, but never attains, the origin $(0,0).$ [we have $f^2+g^2=e^{-2x}>0$]